# Creating a taxonomy tree in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wiki, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to finish transferring platforms to wordpress for a client. Their old CMS had a system that let them create "wikis", each with their own article list, most popular, search and tag clouds.

All the wiki plugins I can find create a single wiki, and usually as a separate system like a help desk. I came up with a convoluted system using taxonomies and custom post types, but I feel like it's much more messy than is actually helpful.

What I need, I think, is a way to register a custom master post type, with a series of taxonomies inside it to keep the posts organized:
Blog type: Wiki > Wiki Type: this wiki, that wiki > Post, and then a way to call only the one wiki type at a time for tags and such. Does anyone know how to get that working easily?

I tried plugins (All only create one wiki), taxonomies (don't seem to have a way to separate out tag calls). I got a system working by using custom taxonomies with ACF, so there's a checkbox on each post for which wiki it is, and each wiki has it's own tag box which can be summoned separately, but it's unwieldy after 5 separate tag boxes, muchless the 20+ I still need to do. I considered a solution having every wiki created by a different user, but that requires generating a new user for every wiki, which also gets unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem : you would need a custom taxonomy to be "wiki" (like "wiki1", "wiki2", and so on), and another to be "wiki tags" ("tag1", "tag2"...). You need the wiki tags to be bound to one specific wiki (or to many, maybe ?), which is not implemented natively in WordPress. Multisite is not an option, because you need admin users to be able to create wikis themselves. Am I correct ?

If it's the case, you might want to go for a custom field in the "wiki tags" taxonomy that would allow you to bind a tag to a specific wiki (found [that](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/add-custom-fields-to-taxonomy-terms.html) after a quick search). Then you could add a [custom meta box](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/#:%7E:text=Top%20%E2%86%91-,Adding%20Meta%20Boxes,and%20the%20wporg_cpt%20edit%20screen.) in the post edition page, to select the tags in a list that would filter itself when you choose the wiki for the post. Then you would need to create a set of functions that make handy the retrieving of the posts and tags.

Anyway since there are no real "scopes" abilities that are native to WP, I think you should expect hard work on both the backend and the interface, regardless of the structural choices you're going to make.